# SAS Calculate last 15 days of withdrawals

Tags: sas

I have a dataset full of transactions and each observation has account number, date, and transaction amount variables. Obviously multiple transactions will have the same account number.

I want to calculate the total transaction amount for each account number over the last 15 days for each transaction.

So my final dataset set will be a set of transactions with the following variables: account number, date, transaction amount, and total transaction amount over past 15 days.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: How to check if each of the other transactions is in the timeframe and add it's transaction amount to the total.

Comment: Or maybe just how to create an array out of my dataset, then using my current transaction I could loop through every other transaction and check if the account number is the same and date is in the timeframe and then I would add the transaction amount to the total.

Comment: Look up `proc means` if you're not familiar with it.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Naw, don't think that's going to do it for me. I need the new variable appended to the end of the row.

How could I cycle through every observation?

Comment: I'd suggest that you provide some sample data and the code you have so far.  Doing this is far more likely to result in a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with proc SQL with a self merge, remove the where clause here, it's just for example. 
This does actually do two passes of the data but it will be in one proc.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select a.stock, a.date, a.open, sum(b.open) as total_open
from sashelp.stocks as a
left join sashelp.stocks as b
on a.date-b.date between 0 and 15
and a.stock=b.stock
where a.stock='IBM'
group by a.stock, a.date, a.open
order by a.stock, a.date;
quit;
```